# How can I create a custom pop up on marker click using Gmaps.js?

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

I'm using [GMaps.js](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/markers.html) to implement some Google Maps functionality on my website. This library is fantastic and saved me a ton of work.

I'm trying to create a custom popup that appears when someone clicks on a marker. I saw one of the [examples](http://hpneo.github.com/gmaps/examples/markers.html) that uses `infoWindow` but that just shows a white box.

Is there some way to customize the look of this box? Change the background color, borders, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: Your your own HTML *inside* the infoWindow.

Comment: I know I can write every HTML I want inside the info window, but I don't want that gaudy white box and shadow. I need to completely customize the box. I'd settle with just applying some CSS to it and working from there. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[This page](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infowindow_custom/infowindow-custom.html)** demonstrates that it's possible to customize infoWindows.

I can't find an explanation but the customization appears to be achieved in a script on the page - "view source" then peel your eyeballs in preparation for lots of code.